# React Native Onesignal OnPressed notification is not working in release build

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal

I have created a react native app in this I have to add the push notification that has been done by me and for push notification, I have used the react-native-onesignal package. but there is some issue with the notification, in my app when I send the notification the app receives the notification but when I try to open the notification then the app stuck (hangs on the current screen) also I have added the Onpress event listener for the one signal notification. The notifications onpressed event listener is not working properly in my app. with this listener I have to open my notification page.

The code i have added is this

```js
OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', (e) => this.onOpened(e, this));
```

and the function is

```js
onOpened(openResult, component) {
  component.props.navigation.navigate('allnotification'); 
}
```

if anyone knows the solution please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @TrueTiem No the app crashed a when the notification is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened.bind(this));
  }

onOpened(openResult) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')
}
```

Comment: I am having problem with the released build as in the development build it is working fine.